# Elegant way to structure models into subfolders without creating submodules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have numerous models in my app/models folder. I'd like to clean this folder up a little bit. Move models that belong to each other in subfolders. The problem is that by convention the model class is namespaced into an according module.

E.g.

app/models/blog/post.rb
app/models/blog/comment.rb
app/models/user.rb

so that:

app/models/blog/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord
end
```

and not

```
class Blog::Post < ActiveRecord
end
```

Comment: add to *config/application.rb* `config.autoload_paths += Dir[ Rails.root.join('app', 'models', "blog", '**/') ]`

Answer (score 82):

Here is what I used for Rails 3:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
```

This configuration tells Rails to scan all the app/models subfolders recursively and load all found models. No namespacing required.

Comment: This wasn't working recursively for me. Instead I used: Dir[ Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '**/') ]

Comment: That's strange, because I use it on several projects and it's working recursively for me. What is your Ruby/RoR version?

Comment: What should I do if I have more nested subfolders, like "app/models/user/premium/"?

Comment: it doesn't work in the activerecord association. You can call Post and Comment, but cannot call Post.first.comments. Any idea?

Comment: +1 for freshfunk's comment. If you'd use JohnZ's answer, you would also add plain files in the top-level directory, e.g. in app/models

Comment: `Dir[ Rails.root.join('app/models/**/') ]` will load recursively, `Dir[ Rails.root.join('app/models/**') ]` won't

Answer (score 12):

We needed to do this, and there is a very simple way.

move your models into the sub-folders, and then tell rails to load files from all subfolders in your  environment.rb file:

```
config.load_paths += Dir["#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models/*"].find_all { |f| File.stat(f).directory? }
```

No namespacing required, and the models can be referred to as normal in your app

Comment: Haven't gotten into rails 3 yet :(

Comment: This works in Rails 3.

Modify config/application.rb: add app/models/<dir> to the autoload_paths - no namespace is required

Comment: Code golf: `config.load_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/*/**/"]`

Comment: Didn't work for me. 'models' folder was still somehow loaded with subfolders, which resulted in 'Expected <file> to contain <namespace>::<class>

Answer (score 4):

I also created subfolders, and then added the following to the application.rb file:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]
```

But doing this alone isn't enough when subfolders are named using the same name as a model (e.g., a folder 'user' containing several files, one of which is 'user').  This was causing all kinds of errors in my code until I found that it could be solved by simply giving the folders names that are different from the models (e.g., 'user models') they contain.  I found the suggestion at http://www.williambharding.com/blog/technology/rails-3-autoload-modules-and-classes-in-production/, which actually points to this question.

Comment: At least in Rails 4, this line did not seem to work, until I changed `config.root` to `Rails.root`.

Comment: Ah yes, this is a fine gotcha. The reference there identifies this as esoteric: "You have a model in a subdirectory, where the name of the subdirectory matches the name of the model". However, I just had this happen because I have a model which is defined in inflectors to be same singluar and plural. I was fine with paths like users/user.rb and posts/post.rb. But in this case, I had series/series.rb, causing the problem. And it's not immediately obvious that the problem is only with one file. Renaming to series_models/series.rb worked.

Answer (score 3):

So I used to have in Rails 2 something like this:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]
```

And the following files:

- app/models/user/base.rb: `class User::Base`
- app/models/user/admin.rb: `class User::Admin`

When I upgraded to Rails 3, I kept getting an error along these lines: `Expected .../app/models/user/foo.rb to define Foo`. This clearly seemed crazy since Rails 2 automatically assumed that what you put in user/foo.rb would be `User::Foo` not just `Foo`.

So the way I ended up solving this was getting rid of model subdirectories in `autoload_paths` and doing something like this:

I created app/models/user.rb with:

```
module User
  autoload :User, 'user/base'
  autoload :User, 'user/admin'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could look upon RailsEngines. It's not exactly what you need, but could gave you some ideas.

Other than that, if your script seems to work fine (you could also just read all the files on each subfolder on model and require them), I don't see any problem against it.

Answer (score 1):

this version of Tilendor's solution works with Rails 3

config.load_paths and RAILS_ROOT are deprecated in Rails 3, also you should put it in the config block of the config/application.rb, not environment.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root.to_s}/app/models/*"].find_all { |f| File.stat(f).directory? }
```

Comment: A little cleaner is config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root.to_s}/app/models/**/"]

Answer (score 1):

In my Rails 3.2.3 app, after i moved some models to subdirectories, i have stumbled into errors like

```
Expected /.../.../app/models/project/project_category.rb to define Project::ProjectCategory
```

for association calls (example:  Project.first.project_category).

In the end, the workaround i found was to set :class_name for every association to model in subdirectory...

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :project_category, :class_name => "::ProjectCategory"

end
```

"::" part here points to Rails that ProjectCategory model has no namespace, despite the fact that is defined in a 'models/project' subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Rails 5.

Adding the following to `application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[ Rails.root.join('app/models/**/') ]
```

Beware though that you cannot have the same name on your folder as any  of your models.

Answer (score 0):

Until I find a better solution I've created a init.rb in the app/models folder:

app/models/init.rb

```
%w[blog].each do |folder|
  path = [File.dirname(__FILE__), folder, "*.rb"].join('/')
  Dir[path].each {|file| require file }  
end
```

Servers the purpose until now.

Comment: Does this reload the models for every request?

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers didn't work for me. Somehow 'models' folder was loaded with subfolders, which resulted in 'Expected  to contain ::.

Most of my subdirs were STI classes so I've moved them to app/models_sti//*. Then all I needed to do was to put in `application.rb`

```
#config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root.to_s}/app/models/**/"]
# Loaded dynamically (cache_classes == false ?)
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'models').to_s
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root.to_s}/app/models_sti/*"].find_all { |f| File.stat(f).directory? }

# Eager_load_paths - used only when cache_classes == true [rails spec says so]
config.eager_load_paths.delete_if do |path|
  # If I didn't delete it from eager_load_paths I got errors even in develop
  path == Rails.root.join('app', 'models_sti').to_s
end
config.eager_load_paths += config.autoload_paths
```