# Organizing a lot of models that use STI in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, single-table-inheritance

I have a scenario where I am going to be creating a large number of models that use STI and I'm wondering what the best way to organize this is.  I already have other models using STI and I really do not want to add any more files to my models folder.  Is there any way to create a folder and add the models using STI there (there could be upwards of 40 b/c each uses its own methods to scrape a different site, but they all save the same data)?  This seems like it would be best, or I could add them all to one file but I would rather separate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a new directory is fine. Make sure you add it to the load paths in `environment.rb`, though.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445341/rails-elegant-way-to-structure-models-into-subfolders-without-creating-submodule