# ruby on rails sub directory inside in the 'Views' main directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

am a newbie in ruby on rails and am stuck with a simple problem of routing.

I have my controller 'sub' and the 'Views' folder containing the add,edit,new erb files.

In my routes file, i have 'map.resources :subs'.

Until now, everything is fine.

Problem:
I moved the add,edit,new erb files into a subfolder called 'admin' inside the 'Views' main directory.
I have no idea how to call those erb files from that 'admin' subdir.

By default, it is looking for  /app/views/subs/index.html.erb, and i want it to look in /app/views/subs/admin/index.html.erb

Please can anyone tell me how to do this.

Many many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest a different approach because it seems what you want to do is admin routing. In your routes.rb write

```
  namespace :admin do     
    resources :subs
  end
```

then put your views in the subdirectory views/admin/subs

also, put your controller in the subdirectory controllers/admin and namespace them with "Admin" too, e.g.

```
class Admin::StubsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  your_code_goes_here
end
```

of course, then you need an application_controller.rb in the controllers/admin dir as well. But you cold also derive from ApplicationController then that is not necessary.

your controller can be called through the url /admin/subs

does that help?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) Yes, it's been of much help indeed

Answer (score 2):

You could explicitly render your templates within your controller actions, like this:

```
render :template => "subs/admin/index"
```

Comment: nice solution, i used it to figure out this answer which is a more general solution! https://stackoverflow.com/a/52416891/8787160

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner in RoR.

What I wanted was to group all views (such as a mobile friendly version) in 1 folder but not end up with an extra namespace OR create new method in controllers. `localhost:3000/posts` calls:

`class Post < ActiveRecord`

and not

`class Admin::Post < ActiveRecord`

BUT load the views in `views/android/posts/index.html.erb`

Because this was my Google first hit, the link below is to an alternative answer that took sometime for me to find.

[Rails: Elegant way to structure models into subfolders without creating submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445341/rails-elegant-way-to-structure-models-into-subfolders-without-creating-submodul)