# how to route your sub-folder in views Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, routes, subdirectory

Can anyone please shed some light on how to route your sub-folder's .html.erb files?? which is placed like this:

```
view/pages/en/index.html.erb
```

and to route this i am doing following things on route.rb

```
match ':lang/index', :to => 'pages/en#index'
```

and for a link code, I have this on the header

```
<%= link_to "Home", index_path %>
```

The error i am getting is

```
 Routing Error
 uninitialized constant Pages
```

routes:

[image]

Comment: where you getting that error? post the backtrace

Comment: Please don't edit answers into the question. Post the same content as an answer below, and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, There is no way to route to a view. You can route an URL to a controller's action. That action is responsible for rendering the views.

you can use namespaced routing to put the resources in the sub folder.

...

What i wanted to write already written by @TuteC. Just follow that link and yes you can get language specific thing out of box as he explained.

Answer (score 3):

Namespaces will organize your code and views in subfolders: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

If just need only the `views/pages` folder organized that way, you could do in `PagesController` something like:

```
render "#{I18n.locale}/#{action_name}"
```

A question: why would you like `view/pages/en/index.html.erb` instead of `view/pages/index.en.html.erb`? That would work out of the box.

Comment: simply because I will have another folder such as 'es' where it would have .html.erb files with relevant translation. I could use internationalization API, but this is how it is got to be done according to the specification!

Comment: Just added a faster way of organizing the views in that way.

Comment: again, I do not require to use translation API at all, at the moment it is only just static routing to folders such as 'en' (for english), 'es' (spanish), 'de'(german) which are inside the view->pages-> 'en' 'es' 'de' etc

Comment: oh ok. Anyway serves as example that you may render any view if you pass to the `render` action an appropiate string. Best!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**
This is how it works for route.rb:-

```
match ':lang/index', :to => 'pages#index'
```

Render it on your controller:-

```
def index
  render "pages/en/index"
end

def about
  render "pages/#{params[:lang]}/about"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this for a while and finally figured out an easy solution:

config/routes.rb

```
get 'pages/:first/:second/:third' => 'pages#show'
```

Then in your PagesController

```
def show
    render "/pages/#{params[:first]}/#{params[:second]/#{params[:third]}"
end
```

Then in your views it will render any of the following:

```
pages/index => pages/index.html.erb
pages/index/en => pages/index/en.html.erb
pages/foo/bar/hello-world => pages/foo/bar/hello_world.html.erb
```

The best thing about this is that it is simple and you can extend it indefinitely. Allows easy cleaning up of the views folders if all you are doing is rendering basic templates.