# How to organize MVC structure with big amount of models/controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have got a project with about 50 controllers and 60 models.

It is quite difficult to work in that mess.

How can I improve that scructure?

Now I am creating namespaces for some logical parts of my application and store them in separate folders. But for models this have got some side effects.

Comment: side effects for models? just beware not naming folders with the name of actual models otherwise Rails will assume wrong namespacing.

Comment: @apneadiving, there is a bunch of problems: table refferences are broken, link helpers are broken, some issues with migrations and generators, issues with routing. All this can be easily solved but it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can organize your classes in subfolders - you don't even need to structure them into submodules (but you can if you want to).

See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445341/rails-elegant-way-to-structure-models-into-subfolders-without-creating-submodule) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring is a discipline that deals with that kind of problem.

Consider this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321603508).

Comment: I am talking not about code refactoring, but about organizing files. I believe this book is talking about helpful but different thing

Answer (score 0):

you can refactor your code using namespace.

Comment: That is what I do, but I don't like this. There are many bugs while using namespaces