# Rails solution structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to build a rails solution which will have more that one area for example i have an area for managers another for users and other for admin. Because each of the area has a number of controllers i don't think is a good idea to have all the controllers in one place because there will be a lot of controllers and it will be harder to mange the code also i want to be able to use some parts of the application like an api. Here is what i have in mind for how the solution should be structured:

```
/
  product_library
  users_library
  managers
    app
    config
    public
    ....
  users
    app
    config
    public
    ....
  admin
    app
    config
    public
    ....
  shared
    app
    config
    public
    ....
```

How can i setup a rails solution to which can allow me to instantiate classes from product_library and user_library and will allow me to use some of the functionality or views from the shared (project or library) ?
If my idea of structuring the solution is bad please let me know , i'm open to suggestion on a better structure. Keep in  mind that i need separate parts for product library and user library so it can be used in other projects. Also any documentation on how big rails projects are structured is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do it within Rails normal structure but with subfolders under each of the MVC components.

```
app
  controllers
    managers
    users
    admin
    shared
  models
    "By default Rails doesn't expect folders in here but it can be done...see below"        
  views
    managers
    users
    admin
    shared
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445341/rails-elegant-way-to-structure-models-into-subfolders-without-creating-submodule) if you want to separate your models.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was very helpful it give me an idea on how to build future application and how to refactor others.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet might be to have separate applications.  Each would point to the same database.  You could put your product_library and users_library stuff in a gem to be loaded by each app.  Or just get ghetto with it and put that library stuff in a directory that's symlinked into each app.

Comment: @Mihai This is the main way I've seen things like this done before. You might also look into Rails Engines, which are like live-template applications you can include either as a gem or a plugin into your app. A great resource on using and creating engines is [Crafting Rails Applications](http://www.amazon.com/Crafting-Rails-Applications-Development-Programmers/dp/1934356735/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1308085594&sr=8-1) by Jose Valim, a main Rails core contributor.

Comment: This makes the most sense.. especially if you need to use product/user stuff in other projects.

Comment: My development machine is on windows 7. I will use the gem idea for the product and user library. But for project structure i think the solution that NullRef has is better.