# Rails 3 controller and model subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-routing

I am writing a Rails 3.2.6 app.  I want to separate my controllers and models into subfolders to keep my code clean.  I have ensured that the model and its subdirectory name are not the same.  However, I find that the code fails if the controller subdirectory name and the model subdirectory name are the same.

The following application structure works fine:

```
test
  app
    controllers
      postcnt
        posts_controller.rb
    models
      postmdl
        post.rb
```

but the following structure doesn't:

```
test
  app
    controllers
      postnsp
        posts_controller.rb
    models
      postnsp
        post.rb
```

When I call the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/postnsp/posts
```

I get a 500 error with the message:

```
LoadError in Postnsp::PostsController#index
Expected /Users/dev/code/test/app/models/postnsp/post.rb to define Postnsp::Post
```

In the above examples I followed the advice here to eliminate model namespacing:
[Rails: Elegant way to structure models into subfolders without creating submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445341/rails-elegant-way-to-structure-models-into-subfolders-without-creating-submodul)

and added

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
```

to my application.rb file

For the second (failing) example the relevant files are as follows:

post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :name
end
```

posts_controller.rb:

```
class Postnsp::PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  @posts = Post.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @posts }
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Test::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :postnsp do resources :posts end
```

Can anyone explain why the subdirectories can't be the same?  I assume it's something to do with the creation of the postnsp module for the posts_controller.rb but I can't understand why it's preventing the creation of the model.  I would like to have consistency in the directory structure naming in both the controller and model folders should I require it.

Comment: I think it should be `class Postnsp::Post < ActiveRecord::Base` in the model .rb file too. (prefix `Postnsp`)

Comment: See my response to Draiken below.  Both examples above do not have namespaced models - one works, one doesn't.  I don't want to change the model, rather I want to know what in the design of rails is preventing the second variant working.

Comment: Probably due to how auto loading works in Ruby. This is probably one of the areas where you are fighting against "the rails way" (good or bad, no comment!). But why do you want to separate into directories? What is it achieving for you apart from the "feeling of clean"? ("I have ensured that the model and its subdirectory name are not the same." => you've already fought against rails once, expect more!)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm porting an app from Rails 2 to Rails 3 and it has around 70 controllers and 70 models so a flat directory structure becomes unmaintainable.  Both directory structures I showed above work fine in Rails 2 but in Rails 3 the second one is broken.  Before I go changing the app I really want to understand what's changed and make sure I'm not missing any simple fixes which will help me to maintain the current structure.

Comment: Sadly I haven't found any other solution for this, but just a note that your fix of renaming the model subfolder worked for me. I just renamed to [subfolder]_models, changed the autoload path, and all worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Post` is in the `postnsp` directory, it expects the model to also be scoped by the namespace.

Try changing your `Post` to `Postnsp::Post < ActiveRecord::Base`

**UPDATE**

Okay, I tried an app to do exactly what you told, and I think I know what's wrong...
Since you're inside a namespaced controller, when you use `Post` it actually looks for `Postnsp::Post`, in order to use the base class you must use `::Post` and then everything worked for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the responses but I don't want to have to namespace the models.  I don't want database tables named postnsp_posts (or having to override the table name in every model) just by virtue of the fact that I've structured my application into directories.  Other posts (including the one referenced in my question) explain how to avoid namespacing models and that works fine in the Rails console but they don't address how Controllers in subfolders can call those namespace-free models.  I really want to know why the first directory structure in my question works and the second one doesn't.

Comment: I updated my posts_controller.rb code to use @post = ::Post.all and that made no difference (I agree that it should).  As I mentioned in the comments on my original question, both examples in my question work with Rails 2.  I was really wanting to know what was changed in ApplicationController in Rails 3 (and where) to imply the controller namespacing.  Even if I can get the ::Post convention to work I don't want to have to change every reference in my code to the "::" syntax to have it work with Rails 3.  I want to know if there's a simple fix or configuration to work around the issue.

Comment: The problem lies in the constant lookup that Rails uses. It bases lookups on the current `module` by default. I am not sure you can mess with that. I have never used models in folders specifically because of this errors and inconsistencies that might happen within rails itself.