# ActiveAdmin doesn't find models in subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I structured my over 100 models in subfolders and adapted the autoload path by

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
```

in my application.rb (as recommended at [Rails: Elegant way to structure models into subfolders without creating submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445341/rails-elegant-way-to-structure-models-into-subfolders-without-creating-submodul))

Unfortunately ActiveAdmin can't find now the original models anymore and brings the error " uninitialized constant".

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: 100 models? Is that DRY??

Comment: yes, they are mostly DRY. It is a SAAS for a complex industry.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'folder_name/model_name.rb'

ActiveAdmin.register ModelName do
  ...
end
```

works for me